# MS SQL SERVER 2008 install

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

If i have a one processor license for ms sql 2008 can i just click to turn on the other processor in the event i buy another license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SQL Server 2008 sets the max degree of parallelism to '0' which is basically use all available processors for processing.  I don't think that SQL Server licensing does any checking to see if you only have a one-processor license on a > 1 proc server.  You could also set max degree of parallelism to '1' in a multi-proc server and still fall within the licensing guidelines.

It's my understanding that it's the honor system with regard to the licensing.

Comment: and I believe is physical processor, not the amount of cores

Answer (score 1):

That won't cut it.  You have to remove the extra processor from the server to be legit.  Having the processor in the server, even if not using it requires a license.